# Random shuffle with Mongoose Pagination

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pagination

In my Mongoose/Express app, I was previously using the following algorithm to shuffle an array of vendors:

```
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
}

let vendors = await Vendor.find();
shuffleArray(vendors);
```

However, I have since introduced Mongoose Pagination, which changes the code as shown below.  But the shuffleArray algorithm no longer seems to work after introducing pagination. It there a way I can still achieve a random shuffle on the array while maintaining pagination? I am open to changing the shuffle algorithm or approaching the shuffle a different way if needed, though I don't have much knowledge on how to do this.

New pagination code:

```
let vendors = await Vendor.paginate({
    page: req.query.page || 1,
    limit: 20
});
```

Comment: Can you show more details about what doesn't work?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc basically it doesn't shuffle the order of the vendors (which is what I want). With the pagination applied, it always shows the vendors in the same order every time. Thanks

Comment: May be you need to `shuffleArray(vendors.docs);`

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc that was something obvious that I missed, thanks.  If I use vendors.docs, it does shuffle the array, though not quite in the way I need it, as it only shuffles according to the page limit.  For example, if I have 60 records, but the page limit is 20, then it always shuffles the same 20 records on the first page, rather than shuffling the full 60 records. Any ideas how I can shuffle the full array?

Comment: I guess this is because the shuffle is being implemented AFTER the pagination, hence it is only returning the records on page 1. Is there a way therefore I could shuffle the docs BEFORE applying the pagination?

Comment: I afraid you can't do server side pagination with random shuffle.